# How to build elastic search query on Term condition in C# with NEST?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I want ElasticSearch data with a simple term condition.
The data exists and meets the search condition, but my request did not work.
With the MatchAll function, I get data that meets the term condition.

I'm using the Nest package

```
var result = _client.Search<RawCacheProposition>(x => x
                      .Query(q => q
                        .Term(t => t.Field(f => f.CabinClass).Value("Y"))));
```

I didn't have any error but "result.Documents" is empty.

Comment: Could you please share which version of NEST and elasticsearch are you using? Index mapping would be useful as well.

Comment: Can you elaborate so that we can help you out

Comment: version of NEST: 6.8.0 and elasticsearch: 6.3 installed on Google Kubernetes Engine.

Comment: this solution found yesterday works:

`
var result = _client.Search<RawCacheProposition>(x => x
                      .Query(q => q
                        .Term(t => t.Field("cabinClass.keyword").Value("Y"))));
`


but i don't want to use a string to define my property.

It seems that NEST use a POST api request instead of use a GET api request.(my first solution work with a GET request -> test on elasticsearch head extension with json request with GET method)

Comment: You can use `Suffix` extension method to make it working with NEST `t.Field(f => f.CabinClass.Suffix("keyword"))`.